# Destructuring object properties from an array of objects and rendering those properties into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I currently have two objects (it's a lot but this is what I want to draw your attention to.) As you can see, this is an array of objects. What I want to do is to pull out specified properties of each object and store that in an array. So for example I would want object property `Price`, I'd like to get each `Price` property of the object and store all of it in an array that would only contain it's value like in this case : `[215.23,215.23]`

```
 [{
        CompanyName: "Microsoft Corp.",
        Date: 1606503905,
        Price: 215.23,
        Quantity: 50,
        Symbol: "MSFT",
        TotalCost: 10761.5
      },
      {
        CompanyName: "Microsoft Corp.",
        Date: 1606503913,
        Price: 215.23,
        Quantity: 25,
        Symbol: "MSFT",
        TotalCost: 5380.75
      }
    ]
```

Here's a snippet:

```
function RadialChart(props) {
    const { transactionData } = props; //Array of objects stored here
    transactionData.map((data) => {console.log(data.TotalCost)})
```

I tried using useState and the map method but I don't think I was doing it right. When I was using map, I declared a `const arr= []` then did an `arr.concat(data.TotalCost)` and that didn't work. Please let me know if you guys have a solution. Thank you.

Comment: `const RadialChart = propName => transactionData.map(o => o[propName])`? Which would return array of `Price` values on `RadialChart('Price')`

Comment: and, by the way, get your input data fixed (missing commas aren't cool - the input is not suitable to play with)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want just an array of prices, then just `map` it and return the price:

```js
const prices = transactionData.map((data) => data.Price);
console.log(prices); // [215.23, 215.23]
```

Comment: Jesus Christ, I can't believe I missed it. I was doing all this crazy stuff with useState, useEffect and spread operators that it was this simple. Thanks for pointing that out, the mental exhaustion is taking it's toll.

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want simply with map.

```js
const myArray =  [{
        CompanyName: "Microsoft Corp.",
        Date: 1606503905,
        Price: 215.23,
        Quantity: 50,
        Symbol: "MSFT",
        TotalCost: 10761.5,
      },
      {
        CompanyName: "Microsoft Corp.",
        Date: 1606503913,
        Price: 215.23,
        Quantity: 25,
        Symbol: "MSFT",
        TotalCost: 5380.75,
      }
    ]
    
    
  console.log('CompanyName', myArray.map(x => x.CompanyName))
  console.log('Date', myArray.map(x => x.Date))
    console.log('Price', myArray.map(x => x.Price))
  console.log('TotalCost', myArray.map(x => x.TotalCost))
```

If you want to set it to state...

declare useState

```
const [ price, setPrice ] = useState([]);
```

setPrice

```
setPrice(myArray.map( x => x.Price ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use destructuring and map to get the prices.  (Just adding destructuring to @Aplet123's suggestion)

```js
const data = [
  {
    CompanyName: "Microsoft Corp.",
    Date: 1606503905,
    Price: 215.23,
    Quantity: 50,
    Symbol: "MSFT",
    TotalCost: 10761.5,
  },
  {
    CompanyName: "Microsoft Corp.",
    Date: 1606503913,
    Price: 123.23,
    Quantity: 25,
    Symbol: "MSFT",
    TotalCost: 5380.75,
  },
];

const prices = data.map(({ Price }) => Price);
console.log(prices);
```